# ASP.net mvc with angular js Failed to start 'npm'

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, npm, asp.net-mvc-5, npm-install

I'm Working on Visual Studio 2022.
tried to npm install in node js latest version and also in 14.17.
tried to npm install latest angualr version and aslo tried 8.3.22.
clean cache before installing also doesn't work.
the error is :

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)

InvalidOperationException: Failed to start 'npm'. To resolve this:.

[1] Ensure that 'npm' is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
Current PATH enviroment variable is: C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Cloudflare\Cloudflare WARP\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\H & M\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\H & M\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\H & M\AppData\Local\spicetify;C:\Users\H & M\AppData\Roaming\npm
Make sure the executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.

[2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.Npm.NpmScriptRunner.LaunchNodeProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)

Stack Query Cookies Headers
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout<T>(Task<T> task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, string message)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task<Uri> baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, bool proxy404s)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass2_0+<<UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer>b__0>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
HR.ManagerPortal.Startup+<>c+<<Configure>b__13_0>d.MoveNext() in Startup.cs
+
                await next.Invoke();
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Show raw exception details
InvalidOperationException: Failed to start 'npm'. To resolve this:. [1] Ensure that 'npm' is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories. Current PATH enviroment variable is: C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Cloudflare\Cloudflare WARP\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\H & M\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\H & M\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\H & M\AppData\Local\spicetify;C:\Users\H & M\AppData\Roaming\npm Make sure the executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH. [2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.Npm.NpmScriptRunner.LaunchNodeProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.Npm.NpmScriptRunner..ctor(string workingDirectory, string scriptName, string arguments, IDictionary<string, string> envVars)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(string sourcePath, string npmScriptName, ILogger logger)

Show raw exception details
```

Package.Json:

```
{
  "name": "client-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^4.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.3.0",
    "@mondal/org-chart": "^8.1.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.5",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.7.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.2.6",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-diagrams": "^17.4.41",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^21.2.2",
    "ag-grid-community": "^21.2.2",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "angular-ng-autocomplete": "^1.1.15",
    "angular-text-input-autocomplete": "^0.3.0",
    "angular-webstorage-service": "^1.0.2",
    "basicprimitives": "^5.6.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.10.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.13.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ng-bootstrap-to-bootstrap-3": "^0.7.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.10",
    "ng2-org-chart": "^1.1.2",
    "ng2-panzoom": "^2.2.2",
    "ng2-tooltip-directive": "^2.8.17",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^1.8.0",
    "ngx-pinch-zoom": "^2.3.4",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.22",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.22",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

npm i errors

```
found 236 vulnerabilities (2 low, 97 moderate, 110 high, 27 critical) in 1522 scanned packages
  run `npm audit fix` to fix 110 of them.
  118 vulnerabilities require semver-major dependency updates.
  8 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.

J:\Web dev\DotNet Core\MO-HR\HR.ManagerPortal\ClientApp>npm audit fix
npm WARN @fullcalendar/angular@4.3.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @fullcalendar/angular@4.3.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-font-awesome@3.1.2 requires a peer of font-awesome@^4.7.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-text-input-autocomplete@0.3.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.4.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.1 requires a peer of jasmine-core@>=3.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-bootstrap-to-bootstrap-3@0.7.0 requires a peer of @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@^1.0.0-alpha.20 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng2-org-chart@1.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=4.0.0 <5.0.0 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng2-tooltip-directive@2.8.17 requires a peer of @angular/common@^7.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng2-tooltip-directive@2.8.17 requires a peer of @angular/core@^7.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-toastr@11.3.2 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\karma\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ moment@2.29.4
+ jquery-ui@1.13.2
added 63 packages from 70 contributors, removed 28 packages, updated 35 packages and moved 1 package in 55.138s

34 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

fixed 110 of 236 vulnerabilities in 1522 scanned packages
  8 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated
  6 package updates for 118 vulnerabilities involved breaking changes
  (use `npm audit fix --force` to install breaking changes; or refer to `npm audit` for steps to fix these manually)
```

and fix -- force also doesn't fix the problem.

System Variables Node js Path already exists.

i don't want to update or upgrade existing version
hope some body can help and thank you